# Why $ (1- \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2 = 2 (1 - \sin \alpha)(1+ \cos \alpha)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, self-learning, learning

Why  $ (1- \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2 = 2 (1 - \sin \alpha)(1+ \cos \alpha)$?

I am learning trigonometric identities one identity I have to proof is the next:

$ (1- \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2 = 2 (1 - \sin \alpha)(1+ \cos \alpha)$

so I tried to resolve the identity for the left:

$  1 + \sin^2 \alpha+ \cos^2\alpha - 2\sin\alpha + 2\cos\alpha - 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha  $

$=  1 + 1 - 2\sin\alpha + 2\cos\alpha - 2\sin\alpha\cos\alpha  $

$=  2 (1 - \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha\cos\alpha)$

And I got stuck, I did not know what to do, so I went to see the problem's answer and I was going fine, the part I was not able to resolve is the next one:

$  2 (1 - \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha\cos\alpha)$

$=  2 (1  + \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha(1+\cos\alpha))$

$=  2 (1 - \sin \alpha)(1+ \cos \alpha)$

So the question is how did the teacher do the last three steps? I  cant figure it out.

Comment: It is a common factorization. where is it exactly your problem?

Comment: The op says he wants the last three steps explained is all.

Comment: @BabakMiraftab I was not able to figure out the three last steps, that's my problem.

Comment: $2 (1 - \sin\alpha + \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=2 (1 +  \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha  - \sin\alpha\cos\alpha)=2 (1 +  \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha(1+\cos\alpha))$. I moved the position of sin and switched with cos.

Comment: You learn to recognize this kind of things by doing maths

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres check out the answers, I think they should help elucidate things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculated that the left side is equal to $$2(1-\sin\alpha + \cos\alpha -\sin\alpha\cos\alpha).$$

Now, try to prove that the left side is equal to that as well. Try expanding $$(1-\sin\alpha)(1+\cos\alpha)$$

Comment: Oh Now I got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres My pleasure. Remember, if an answer is what you needed, upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

They are just the [distributive property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property)

> $$a(b+c)=ab+ac$$

in the first one we have $a=-\sin\alpha, b= 1, c=\cos\alpha$ which comes from the terms

$$2(1+\underbrace{(-\sin\alpha)}_{a}\cdot\underbrace{1}_{b}+\cos\alpha+\underbrace{(-\sin\alpha)}_{a}\cdot\underbrace{\cos\alpha}_{c})$$

The next step is the same property with $a=(1+\sin\alpha), b=1, c=\cos\alpha$ as seen

$$2(\underbrace{(1+\cos\alpha)}_{a}\cdot \underbrace{1}_{b}+\underbrace{(1+\cos\alpha)}_{a}\underbrace{(1-\sin\alpha)}_{c}).$$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed
$$
(1 - \sin \alpha + \cos \alpha)^2 = (1 - \sin \alpha)^2 + \cos^2 \alpha+ 2(1 - \sin \alpha)\cos \alpha 
$$
$$
= (1 - 2\sin \alpha + \sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha) +  2(1 - \sin \alpha)\cos \alpha 
$$
$$
= 2(1 - \sin \alpha) + 2(1 - \sin \alpha)\cos \alpha = 2(1 - \sin \alpha)(1 + \cos \alpha)
$$